# Fast way to modify Windows/File Explorer view?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I like to set my Windows/File Explorer from the Folder Options/View tab to have the following options:

- check - Always show menus
- check - Show hidden files, folders, or drives
- uncheck - Hide empty drives in Computer Folder
- uncheck - hide extensions for known file types
- uncheck - Hide protected operating system files
- check - Launch folder windows in a separate process
- check - Restore previous folder windows at logon

And then Apply that view to all folders.

Is there a fast way to set this for multiple machines?  Are these stored in a registry setting or ini file?

Comment: These will be stored in a registry key. You can export each of them and then combine them into a single .reg file. Then, you can either run that reg file under each user account that you want to have the settings applied, or find a way to automate loading the user registry hives and applying it from a server, or pushing it out through group policy.

Comment: do you know which key(s)?

Comment: Not specifically, which is why I made that a comment instead of an answer. They shouldn't be too hard to look up one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

- AlwaysShowMenus
- Hidden
- HideDrivesWithNoMedia
- HideFileExt
- ShowSuperHidden
- SeparateProcess
- PersistBrowsers

Comment: excellent.  now i can make a .reg and just put it in a shared folder.